# How to compile new element.attr() in angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I don't realize, how to make work new attribute. $compile works fine for clone(), replaceWith() etc, but, for example, i want to hide any dom element by adding directive:

```
.directive('hidden', function($compile) {
                return {
                    scope:{},
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                        scope.shown = false;
                        element.attr('ng-show','shown');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is actually just for show and hide stuff do as @Max suggested but `ng-show` cannot work if you create the property in the `link` use `controller` function instead.

if the question is an examle for a more complicated scenario you can use below code.

```
// as the compile works with contents string you need the get it.
$compile(element.parent().contents())(scope);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting idea, and works. Obviously, not really good if parent contents a lot of stuff and i got 2 unlogged errors in mozilla's firebug (just error's number and clean console).

Comment: well the errors sound weird can you try the app chrome when the developer toolbar is open. maybe you can get more info.

Comment: With running developer toolbar in chrome i got toolbar's crash :) I think it is bad sign.  
Without toolbar — just works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case that directive is not useful, because it duplicates `ng-show/ng-hide` behaviour.

1. Use `ng-hide/ng-show` directly on DOM-elements
2. Use your custom directive, but do not use `ng-show` inside. Instead of it try `element.hide()` or `element.show()`

Comment: Thank you, but i need to operate with directive's scope. 
Element.hide()/show() can be replaced with adding class and css-style, but i want to get clean directive.

Comment: @philosophocat It's not cleanly to use `bg-show` inside directive to hide element. It has low performance. Don't fear to use jquery inside a directive, because it's expected behaviour for directives

Comment: i think you are right. I'm trying to understand the idea of directives in angular, functionality packing into single essence. "Angular Bootstrap" considered to be good, but  in my opinion — it is too big and not clean for fast understanding. For example, dropdown — https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js
One click to show, one click (anywhere) to hide. And it is packed into a module?